Getting Appstore Server Notifications (V2) Repeatedly
I've set up a webhook to receive notifications from Apple regarding our auto-renewable subscriptions in NodeJS (TypeScript) using AWS Lambda functions and API Gateway (Serverless Architecture). Despite returning a response with status 200 as mentioned in the App Store Connect documentation, the App Store server continues to retry notifications. According to the documentation, if the App Store server doesn’t receive a success response from our server after the initial notification attempt for version 2 notifications, it retries five times at 1, 12, 24, 48, and 72 hours after the previous attempt.
This is how my response looks:
return {
statusCode: 200,
body: 'OK'
};
I've reviewed the App Store Connect documentation but can't understand why I still receive these notifications. If anyone has experience working with ASNs (App Store Server Notifications) in Lambda using NodeJS, please let me know.
I've also tried updating the statusCode key with just status but it didn't work either.
return {
status: 200,
body: 'OK'
};
